# Using same filename for the input in sub-shell and also as output in parent shell will conflict?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-substitution

Referring to [this answer of mine](/a/619798/72456) which I used the same `tmp` file for the input to the process-substitution and also writing the output to the same `tmp` file in parent shell, does this will cause any interruption when reading in process-substitution and writing by the shell?

based on discussion in the comments and [a similar post](/a/393352/72456) I found, seems that should not be conflict, right?

```
grep -xvFf <(cut -d'/' -f1 tmp) ext >> tmp
```

Related discussions in comments:

> This looks very elegant, but isn't `tmp` is being read and written to at
> the same time? – [Quasimodo](/users/388654/)
>
> @Quasímodo no, child-shell opens the `tmp` for reading only and
> redirection is done after `grep` done the processioning thought and
> shell open the `tmp` again for writing (But still I'm not expert on this
> to 100% confirm that) – αғsнιη
>
> @Quasímodo `strace grep …`  shows that it opens by grep and close
> after finish, and so after grep done shell write the output to `tmp`, so
> that will not interrupt at the same time – αғsнιη

Comment: `grep` will first read the whole patterns file, then parse the other file. So before writing any output, it has finished reading the patterns. No recycling of lines will happen. So it will append the output, I guess that even this would work as expected: `grep -f tmp ext >> tmp`.

Comment: if you're on Linux, install the ` moreutils` package and use `sponge`.  Basically, you'd replace the `>> tmp` with `sponge -a tmp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you're doing.

For `grep -f patterns`, `grep` will pretty much have to read the `patterns` file up front, before starting to read the actual data file. Otherwise it couldn't know if the first line matches. So here, you're safe.

Of course if you were use a truncating redirection to the file, it might well get truncated before the command in the process substitution got to read it. But see below.

---

In general, with the output redirected in append mode, I'd be worried about looping the output back to the input. Trying out with GNU grep, it's smart enough to warn about this:

```
$ seq 99999 > foo.txt
$ grep ^1 foo.txt >> foo.txt 
grep: input file ‘foo.txt’ is also the output
```

But if we trick it with a process substitution, it works, and parts of the data get processed repeatedly:

```
$ grep ^1 <(cat foo.txt) >> foo.txt
$ grep -Fx 1933 foo.txt
1933
1933
1933
1933
```

There should of course be just two copies of `1933` there. Your mileage may vary.

---

For the truncating redirection, I tested with the below on Linux:

```
echo moi > hello.txt
cat <(cat hello.txt) > hello.txt >&2;
```

Here, if the redirection to `hello.txt` is processed before the inner cat runs, the result will be no output. On the other hand, if the `cat` in the process substitution runs first, it might get to read the file before it's truncated. Looping that a few times:

```
for x in {1..999}; do echo moi > hello.txt; cat <(cat hello.txt) 3> hello.txt; done
```

gives no output on my system *if it's idle*, but outputs `moi` a few to a few dozen times if a simple busyloop is running at the same time. (`3>` redirection to just truncate the file without affecting the output.)

Comment: @thanasisp, for something like `foo <(cat hello.txt) > hello.txt` I wouldn't be sure about the order. In principle that manual you linked to says that expansions happen first (well, the redirection filename might come from an expansion), and that includes process substitutions. But on the other hand, process substitutions involve starting another asynchronous process, so there's no promises. The shell might well get to the redirection before the other process manages to start and read the file. But anything can happen, and does e.g. on my system under load. See edit..